# Mockito MissingMethodInvocationException when using mock-maker-inline configuration

Tags: android, junit, mockito, android-testing, mockito-kotlin

I am using Mockito to run tests in an android module. 
My tests works fine before adding the configuration for `mock-maker-inline` in `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions` file. But after adding this configuration some of my tests are not working any more.

Here is the code I'm using to mock my class.

```
private static Fragment createMock() {
    final Fragment stubFragment =
            mock(Fragment.class, withSettings().extraInterfaces(MyInterface.class));
    when(((MyInterface) stubFragment).getFragment()).thenReturn(stubFragment);
    return stubFragment;
}
```

And this is the exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException
```

I don't need Mockito inline for this class as it works without it but I need it for some other classes in the same module. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Can you put full exception stacktrace?

Comment: Can you add minimal code that can help us to reproduce the issue?